# Contradictory argument to continous energy spectrum in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-equations

The Schrodinger equation can be formulated as a regular Sturm-Liouville problem along with proper boundary conditions. Now the solution of regular Sturm Liouville problems with suitable boundary conditions have a discrete eigenvalue spectrum, i.e they have a countably infinite number of discrete eigenvalues. Only when the when the problem is singular do we get a continuous eigenvalue spectrum, which is not the case with the Schrodinger equation.

Now one famous case for which we get a continous energy spectrum is the case of a free particle in quantum mechanics. So the question is, why should a continuous energy spectrum be there when the theory says otherwise.

Comment: Observe that the solutions to the free particle don't lie in $L^2$ but in the rigged Hilbert space.

Comment: @Phoenix87 but how come does the solving of a Sturm-Liouville problem can give a continuous spectrum?

Comment: The Sturm-Liouville theorem assumes that the solutions live on a compact interval $[0,1]$ (up to a rescaling). That's not the case for the free particle, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: @HansMoleman, i didn't pay attention enough to the fact that interval was compact. problem solved. thanks.